# MySQL Optimization: Multiple Modes (Most Common Value) in a Single Query

Tags: mysql, optimization, statistics, analytics

A feature of my real estate website allows users to subscribe to a particular market and receive regular updates (called "market analyses") by email. The analyses require a few values to be calculated as a mode (most common value). Upon doing some research, I learned that MySQL [does not have a MODE() function](https://www.benlcollins.com/sql/mysql-averages/) particularly because there might be multiple modes and there might be no mode whatsoever, but also because you cannot even get a single mode without having at least two values in the column.

> Which leads me to this query

```
SELECT AVG(Price) as AveragePrice,
AVG(BedroomsTotal) as AverageNumberOfBedrooms,
AVG(BathroomsTotal) as AverageNumberOfBathrooms,
AVG(SquareFeetTotal) as AverageSquareFeetTotal,
AVG(LotSize) as AverageLotSize,
AVG(AssociationFee) as AverageAssociationFee,
(SELECT PropertyType FROM (SELECT PropertyType, count(PropertyType) AS magnitude
FROM listings
GROUP BY PropertyType
ORDER BY magnitude DESC
LIMIT 1) as mpt) as MajorityPropertyType,
(SELECT magnitude FROM (SELECT PropertyType, count(PropertyType) AS magnitude
FROM listings
GROUP BY PropertyType
ORDER BY magnitude DESC
LIMIT 1) as mptc) as MajorityPropertyTypeCount,
(SELECT ArchitecturalStyle FROM (SELECT ArchitecturalStyle, count(ArchitecturalStyle) AS magnitude
FROM listings
GROUP BY ArchitecturalStyle
ORDER BY magnitude DESC
LIMIT 1) as mas) as MajorityArchitecturalStyle,
(SELECT magnitude FROM (SELECT ArchitecturalStyle, count(ArchitecturalStyle) AS magnitude
FROM listings
GROUP BY ArchitecturalStyle
ORDER BY magnitude DESC
LIMIT 1) as masc) as MajorityArchitecturalStyleCount,
AVG(YearBuilt) as AverageYearBuilt,
(SELECT PropertyCondition FROM (SELECT PropertyCondition, count(PropertyCondition) AS magnitude
FROM listings
GROUP BY PropertyCondition
ORDER BY magnitude DESC
LIMIT 1) as mpc) as MajorityPropertyCondition,
(SELECT magnitude FROM (SELECT PropertyCondition, count(PropertyCondition) AS magnitude
FROM listings
GROUP BY PropertyCondition
ORDER BY magnitude DESC
LIMIT 1) as mpcc) as MajorityPropertyConditionCount
FROM srep.active_listings 
WHERE concat(City, ', ', StateOrProvince)
LIKE "Boston, MA";
```

This query works just fine, but the problem is that it takes 10 seconds to execute with a Query Cost of 11,000 and it doesn't even contain a fraction of the conditional statements that should be in the `WHERE` clause. There are 18 other conditional statements that need to be included.

## The Question(s):

> > How can I optimize this query? Should I be using a newer version of MySQL? Should I be using a different database altogether?

### Current Execution Plan

[image: Current Execution Plan]

### Results

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One improvement is to cut out half the subqueries:

```
    (   SELECT  PropertyType
            FROM  
            (
                SELECT  PropertyType, count(PropertyType) AS magnitude
                    FROM  listings
                    GROUP BY  PropertyType
                    ORDER BY  magnitude DESC
                    LIMIT  1) as mpt
    ) as MajorityPropertyType,
```

-->

```
    (   SELECT  PropertyType
                    FROM  listings
                    GROUP BY  PropertyType
                    ORDER BY  COUNT(*) DESC
                    LIMIT  1
    ) as MajorityPropertyType
```

This particular query would need `INDEX(PropertyType)` (unless it is already the `PRIMARY KEY`).

Another improvement is to avoid hiding indexed columns in function calls:

```
WHERE concat(City, ', ', StateOrProvince) LIKE "Boston, MA"
```

-->

```
WHERE City = 'Boston' AND StateOrProvince = 'MA'
```

together with the composite `INDEX(City, StateOrProvince)` (in either order).  This will avoid scanning the entire table, but instead only look at the Boston MA rows.

Even if there were a `MODE` function, it might not be any faster -- it would have to do essentially what your code does.

Comment: Thank you :) It's good to know how to optimize queries. After wrestling with this code for a while, I ended up using PHP to calculate the mode of a column inside my API. But since this is a question about MySQL, I will mark your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: @ihodonald - See [_this_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) for more on indexing and optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Use another language (like Python) to get the mode of a column. Here's an example using a Web API. You will have to install the `mysqlclient` and `flask` packages before this code will work.

## App.py

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
from statistics import mode
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

RES = {}

@app.route('/')
def bar():
  conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', user='root', cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
  cursor = conn.cursor()
  sql = 'SELECT ArchitecturalStyle FROM srep.active_listings'
  cursor.execute(sql)
  data = cursor.fetchall()
  row = [obj['ArchitecturalStyle'] for obj in data]
  RES["ArchitecturalStyle"] = mode(row)
  return jsonify(RES)
```

---

> ### Test run using all 10 attributes

[image: Python Web API using Flask]

As you can see, it takes 1/10th of the time in Python (compared to MySQL) to get the same results.